# Merging 2 grpahs(bar graph and line graph) in the same graph

Tags: java, javafx, jfreechart

My requirement is to display a graph with line chart and bar chart both have 2 different values. But both the charts must appear in the same graph. There is a way to do it in JFreechart. But my application is completely developed in JavaFX. Please suggest a way to proceed. A sample code to do the same would be really helpful.

Comment: Look among the _Overlaid Charts_ in the [demo](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/samples.html).